# How to efficiently remove nameless attribute from json object js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a very large array of objects and some of the objects have a nameless property. What is an efficient way to remove the property?

```
[ 
  ...
  {
    "phone_number": "***-***-****",
    "category": "Abc",
    "link_to_company": "www.example.com",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "company_name": "test company",
    "": "123", // this need to be removed
    "status": 1
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: `delete obj['']`

Comment: I'm not sure whether the critical issue is the empty value or empty key or both. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: issue is empty key.

Comment: Lawrence, thanks for the reply but what of there are unknown number of empty keys, I know I can use a loop to delete the empty keys but is there a better way to do that?

Comment: there can only be a single key of any name empty or not so can only be one.

Comment: If you're not dealing with a string, it's not JSON. JSON is a text format.

Comment: since your data is array you can doe something like this, data.map(i=>{
delete i[""];
return i;

})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map function should do it.

`array.map(v => { delete v[""]; return v })`

Comment: thanks for the answer but what if there are multiple empty keys?

Comment: @ShafqatJamilKhan It's not possible that there are multiple empty keys in a single object-- all key names in an object are unique.  Therefore there can be a maximum of one key per object that is an empty string.  If you tried to set a second empty key, it would just replace the first.